# Share Invoke is sometimes blank

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a strange bug using a share invoke.

About 1 in 3 attempts to share will result in no text being shared.  Usually the first share will work but further attempts will not work.  Randomly it will start working again.  This happens with bbm, facebook and twitter apps.

The following code is part of a listview listitem.

```
        InvokeActionItem {
            id: invokeActionItem
            title: "Share"
            ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
            imageSource: "asset:///Images/Icons/share_icon.png"
            query {
                mimeType: "text/plain"
                invokeActionId: "bb.action.SHARE"
            }
            onTriggered: {
                query.data = "I just read this and had to share it: " + ListItemData.title + ". ";
                query.data += "Read it here " + ListItemData.shareUrl;
                query.updateQuery();
            }
        }
```

Has anyone got any ideas what could be causing the issue or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invocation is unfortunately broke in QML (works only for text sometimes). You will need to use C++ for it (it works well there)

Comment: Thank you, I've changed all my sharing to use c++ instead.