# Invoke BBM in 10.2

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I can't seem to invoke a BBM chat. Every time I try I get "No matching result from Menu Service for query" and "no result matching query, no armed signal sent"

Is this broken in 10.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I've already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250650/share-invoke-is-sometimes-blank), QML invokation is currently broken. You must use c++.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very upsetting that this is broken, but what can you do.

Comment: Is it fixed in 10.2.1?

Comment: As far as I know, SDK has not changed in 10.2.1. For now SDK cascades 1.2 is the last one, which came with 10.2. If you need help with c++ example let me know. I do hope this will be fixed with 10.3